# Can't see the category name in the link on Custom Post Type Post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type 'Games' and have some categories i have added. when i have created a post and select the category it won't show the category name in the link.

For example:

test.onlinegame.com/games/poker/poker-game-name

But when i view the post it shows only

test.onlinegame.com/games/poker-game-name

Is their anything have to add code when i register Taxonomy or when i register Custom post type?

Can you please tell why its not showing category name in the url?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change permalink structure. wp-admin->setting->permalink and change Custom Structure:

`test.onlinegame.com/%category%/%postname%/`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks